# issue to add a repository from android arsenal

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I am trying to add a PinnedSectionListView from android arsenal.

the way to add say: 
Add the specific repository to your build file:

```
repositories {
   maven {
       url "https://jitpack.io"
  }
```

}

Add the dependency in your build file (do not forget to specify the correct qualifier, usually 'aar'):

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.beworker:pinned-section-listview:v1.0'
```

}

so i did that (build.gradle (Project)):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

}
   task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

build.gradle (Module): apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jonathandg.listviewsections"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.beworker:pinned-section-listview:v1.0@aar'
  //compile 'com.beworker:pinned-section-listview:v1.0'
```

}

then the android studio message is

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.beworker:pinned-section-listview:v1.0
```

The repositoty is in: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/264

Answer (score 1):

Try below Gragle dependency line

```
compile 'com.github.beworker:pinned-section-listview:1.1'
```